# codeigniter file upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am doing the following to upload a file(image) using codeigniter. What I am wanting to do is modify the error message so that it obvious which field the error relates too as there are multiple upload options on the page, below is my upload code,

```
$config['upload_path'] = './media/uploads/users';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '1000';
            $config['max_width']  = '90';
            $config['max_height']  = '60';

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('logo_small'))
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->template->build('users/employer', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                $file = $this->upload->data();
                $logo_small = "small_".$file['file_name'];
            }
```

So basically I want there error message to state Logo Small in the error message, and then if the error relates to Logo large etc I would want it to state that.

Answer (score 2):

easiest way is to edit system/language/english/upload_lang.php with the error message you want.
[image]

Comment: @Krish: It's a big no-no to edit system/core files. If you can't find a language pack in your specific language you can always make a folder in application/language/ and copy all language files from system/language/english/. In your config, change the default language to whatever you named your folder. Then you can hack away on the files in application/language/yourlang/. First post here on stack overflow so couldn't post this as a comment. It doesn't address the multi file issue. Take a peek at the CI forums; I remember reading something about it on there before.

Comment: You don't even need to copy ALL language files. Just copy the one you want to override under the application/language/english/ folder. And whatever you write there overrides system/language/english/